# How do I disable the screen lock in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display-settings

I am running Windows 7 on an HP laptop and after the machine sits idle, it locks and I must enter the password to continue.

I cannot find anything in the control panel to affect this. I thought it was with the screen saver, but I see no settings for this. How can I disable this locking, or alternatively, make the timeout much longer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the Desktop then Personalize/Screensaver and uncheck "On resume require a password"
Or...
Is the laptop going to sleep? If so try this - 
Control Panel/Power Options/Require a password on wakeup

Comment: On my installation it says "On resume, display logon screen".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel → Power Options → Choose when to turn off the display. Then you can set the timeout or even choose never if you want...